# How to download file using tasker?

Tags: downloading, tasker

I need to download files using tasker.(detailed post here on [softwarerecs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/9936))

But I am not able to understand the HTTP_GET task. I want to download different files from various links read from a file, so I tried this settings.

```
Server:Port    http://
Path           %Line  #this is variable that stores link
```

Everything else was optional so I left it as it is.

But I get Unknown host error. So I think I'm doing something wrong.

So can you give an example of downloading a file using tasker?

Comment: *LOL* OK, my comment must have been either too short or confusing :) // For context, the origin on our sister site: [Android application to download pre defined files over WiFi automatically](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/9936/185)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [Documentation](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/help/ah_index.html) (search for HTTP GET).

```
Server:Port    www.example.com:80
Path           path/to/file.txt
```

This is how you should format that request. The server is just the base of the url (www.example.com) and the Path is the path to the file in the respective server (path/to/file.txt).

Comment: I had read the documentation, but was getting it wrong. This solved the problem finally, Thanks!

BTW note that I had to add `output filename` so that the file actually gets saved, otherwise it was not getting saved.

Comment: @RegisteredUser I quote from the documentation: "_Any returned data is stored in the variable %HTTPD if the content type is text-based (max 4K)_". So if you just want to evaluate the response in some way, you don't need to save it to disk first.

Comment: Actually I would be downloading mostly packages for Linux(hundreds of them of small sizes(few  KB's or mb's) which totally make up to 1 or 2 GB)